# How can I create multiple designs from one set of texts?

Tags: text, microsoft-excel

I run multiple newsletters under different names and logos. I’m trying to share the same information graphically on a few of them. I’ve designed each graphic with placeholder text. I’m looking for a way to replace all the text at once on each graphic. They each have different fonts, sizes, and weights which I don’t want to lose.

For example, one is mostly green with large text and another is orange with smaller text. I have about 15 of these. Is it possible to type it once somewhere (like on a spreadsheet) and it will auto-update all the text on all the designs?

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: In Excel?? Excel isn't design software.

Comment: Have you tried to use Imagemagick? You can simply write a script which takes in input the texts and overlays them (in different styles, if needed) on the different logos.

Answer (score 0):

You could create multiple newsletter designs using Adobe InDesign, and use Adobe InCopy to manage the text and content. When you update the text or content in InCopy, those changes will propagate throughout all of the InDesign documents.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML for this. Most newsletters nowadays come from a platform that has HTML as an option. These systems also usually have a way to supply an external link such as css or JS. Add a JS link. Grab the text element you're after in the JS file. Remove the text in the HTML. Populate the text with JS. Not too difficult. Even for rookies.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for `Data Driven Graphics` in Adobe Photoshop. There are details clearly mentioned on Adobe's website.

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-data-driven-graphics.html

A simple tutorial can be found here as well.

https://medium.com/@saurabhjagtap/working-with-data-driven-batch-files-in-photoshop-template-6f8368bfb932

Hope it helps.